# session variable already set

Tags: php, session

I have a 'loginStatus' session variable that gets set on the first page load.  I have an if/else to echo 'setting for the first time' comments to the browser when this 'loginStatus' is being set for the very first time.  The 'setting for the first time' NEVER APPEARS!  I have cleared the cache, I have tried navigating to the index.php page in a browser window outside of my Netbeans development environment -- doesn't matter.  It's as if the session is staying alive permanently on my localhost web server.

Here is the code that detects for the un-initialized 'loginStatus' session variable for the first time the page is loaded and creates/initilizes the session variable just once.

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['loginStatus']))
{
    // we get here ONLY if the 'loginStatus' session variable has already been
    // created for this user's session.  
    $_SESSION['loginStatus'] = "loginStatus already set!"; 
    echo '<br />Just set the loginStatus to: ' .  $_SESSION['loginStatus'] . '<br /><br />';    
}
else
{
    // we only get here the first time this is sent by the server
    // to the user's browser -- so we need to create the 'loginStatus' session
    // variable because the user just came to our site
    // and has not yet logged in. 
    $_SESSION['loginStatus'] = "First-time initialization of loginStatus"; 
    echo '<br />Just set the loginStatus for the first time!<br /><br />';
}
```

I **never** see in the browser window "Just set the loginStatus for the first time!"

All I see in the browser window is:  "Just set the loginStatus to: loginStatus already set!"

In other words -- isset() is wrongly returning ***true*** the very first time my page loads!
I see NO justification for a session variable that is magically already there when I first load the page in the browser!

Although I have loaded the above page several times tonight while writing the code, it was my understanding that when you leave the final page the session gets destroyed.  So why is my $_SESSION['loginStatus']  variable hanging around like a relative who has worn out their welcome?

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION)` at the top of your page, see what it contains, and work from there.

Comment: @Kenaniah -- I did so and saw this:  array
  'loginStatus' => string 'loginStatus already set!' (length=24)

Comment: do a `session_unset(); session_destroy();` to clear out your browser session on the server side.

Comment: Right, but **where** in my code is the right place to add that?  Is there an event or something I can detect in php so that I know when my user has closed all the pages on my site -- because without knowing when that occurs I cannot use session_unset(), session_destroy() at some arbitrary time.  It has to be done when the user has moved on from my site, closed all pages.

Comment: You wipe the session on your logout page. Unless the user actually clicks logout, the session will still exist. Aside from that, the session may get cleaned up through PHP's session garbage collection once it expires, or disassociated with the browser when a user clears their session data.

Answer (score 2):

Session get destroyed when and by the rules set to it (to the session GC) in the php.ini file.This does not happen necessarily when you close the browser or browse to other pages.
Read the session manual in php.net and set the session rules the best way that fits you.

For example, on high security sites, I give the session a time out of few minutes. Means, if the user does no action that makes a request to the server within that time limit, the session will expire.

Comment: What is 'best practice' then to make sure that session data gets deleted when a user leaves the site, I mean **programmatically** in response to, say, a final notification to my web site that 'your user has closed all pages in your site and is leaving, do any clean up that you need to do' ??   What is the common way to do this?  Surely there's a way to 'catch' an 'event' or something that gives me a shot to get rid of unwanted session variables when a user is done with my site!

Comment: @wantTheBest: dude, I'm not a troll. No one cares of expired sessions but newbies, just believe me. You can flag it as much as you want :-) And **there is no** any guaranteed way to "catch" the event of leaving site - just imagine if a client just pulled off his internet cable

Answer (score -1):

not sure,
but it may because you have save this values in your cookies,

try to clear cookies, and reload the page

Comment: false. session data is kept on the server and is NEVER sent over in the cookie. a PHP session cookie contains **ONLY** the session name/ID key pair.